# Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) with pdf_search package?

Tags: r

I never had this issue with any other package , however I am running 2  very basic lines and i am getting error even though i used :

```
library(pdftools)
library(pdfsearch)

file <- system.file('pdf', 'finance.pdf', package = 'pdfsearch')

keyword_search(file, keyword = c('loan', 'interest'),
               path = TRUE)
```

Getting this error :

```
Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
  path[1]="": The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

Earlier used .libPaths and changed my working directories but nothing seem to work for me.What could be the reason as I looking into other questions related to this to solve and tried it but no avail ?

Comment: Are you sure that there is a pdf called 'finance.pdf' at that path? (I may be lloking in the wrong place but https://github.com/cran/pdfsearch/tree/master/inst/pdf suggests there may not be)

Comment: I put my `finance.pdf' on my desktop and set my working directory as desktop too..I have no idea why it is not working . every file I have ever used is read from my working directory and had absolutely no issues except this function

Comment: The system.file just creates a path to a directory that is created when you install pdfsearch. For your own file in your working directroy create your own path to where you have saved your file i.e. `file = "c:/pathToFile/finance.pdf"`

Comment: just did this - `file <- "C:/Users/jack/Desktop/finance.pdf"` - still getting the same error when i run `keyword_search(file, keyword = c('loan', 'interest'),path = TRUE)`

Comment: What does  `file.exists(file)` return  please

Comment: gave me `FALSE` - does it mean it does not read the document ?  Is there a solution to this maybe ? I am using office desktop now . I was getting same error in my personal laptop too

Comment: No it means the document is not at that path. Make sure the path is correct, and make sure the upper/lower case is correct.

Comment: ... can you check that this works okay `file <- system.file('pdf', '1501.00450.pdf', package = 'pdfsearch') ; keyword_search(file, keyword = c('loan', 'interest'), path = TRUE)`

Comment: miraculously it works . Can you pls tell how you got that number to pdf ?

Comment: I got the name of the file from the link in the first comment. But it is in a directory called `pdf` that is created when you install `pdfseacrh`. Have a look at `file` to see where it is on your system (likely be similar to "C:/Users/jack/Documents/R/4.0/pdfsearch/pdf/1501.00450.pdf")

Comment: ... so given that this works, the issue is that `keyword_search` cannot find your pdf and so it looks like the path that you have provided to `finance.pdf" is incorrect

Comment: ah found it . there is `pdf` folder created within R studio library and inside the `pdfsearch`. After copying my file there , it works totally fine now . Thank you for the guidance

Comment: good, glad you got it working but it would be better if you set up your own project directory and stored your pdf in it and read it in from there i.e. create a project directory, I call it projectA here: `dir.create("C:/Users/jack/Documents/projectA/data", recursive = TRUE)` then save "finance.pdf" pdf in the `data` directory and now you can read in with `keyword_search("C:/Users/jack/Documents/projectA/data/finance.pdf", keyword = c('loan', 'interest'), path = TRUE)`

Comment: fantastic . I will surely do :) I stopped using this package a month ago due to this issue. I can seamlessly go forward with this package now